# Chartjs not rendering in navigation stack

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, chart.js

I am using Chart.js for Ionic. The charts load fine on the root page but for each page after the root page in the navigation stack the charts show up blank.

Here's the `.ts` code:

```
ionViewDidLoad()
{
    this.profile_donutCanvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById("profile_donutChart");
     this.profile_donutCtx = this.profile_donutCanvas.getContext('2d');
     this.profile_donutChart = new Chart(this.profile_donutCtx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ['', ''],
            datasets: [{
                data: [100, 0],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(182, 54, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 0
            }]
        },
        options: {
            cutoutPercentage: 95,
            legend:{
            display:false
         },
                    tooltips: {
                        enabled:false
                    }
                }
    });
}
```

and here's the `.html` code:

```
<canvas id="profile_donutChart" width="100" height="100" padding></canvas>
```

Does anybody know what could possibly cause this?

Thanks,
Troy

Comment: Can you please make working copy to https://stackblitz.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar difficulties using Chart.js in ionic (v3). I solved them using the 
**ng2-charts** package, see https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/ which works fine ony any page of the navigation stack.